# PHP upload photo in more than 2 directions

Tags: php, file-upload

I want the uploaded photo to be added to 3 folders. The code is correct, but the photo is only added to the "uploaded" folder. I checked folder permissions and the PHP version; nothing works.

```
if($category == "Ogłoszenia"){
    $file_image = time() . "_" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, "uploaded/".$file_image);  
    copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "../../../subdomena/bip/files/pl/".$file_image);
    copy(resize_image($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 150, 150), "../../../subdomena/bip/files/pl/".$file_image);
} else {
    $file_image = time() . "_" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp, "uploaded/".$file_image);  
}
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` .... moves the file - it will no longer be available via `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` after that. Copy the moved file

Comment: Also, have you checked that `$category == "Ogłoszenia"` is true?

Comment: Also, the two `copy()` you have copies it to the same folder with the same filename.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd copy have the exact same file names.
I added "3" at the end of the 3rd copy to fix that

```php
//1st copy
$file_image = time() . "_" . $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$location = "uploaded/".$file_image;
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location);
if($category == "Ogłoszenia"){
    //2nd copy
    copy($location, "../../../subdomena/bip/files/pl/".$file_image);
    //3rd copy
    copy($location, "../../../subdomena/bip/files/pl/".$file_image."3");
    resize_image("../../../subdomena/bip/files/pl/".$file_image."3", 150, 150);
}
```

Comment: You must always check if move_uploaded_file was successful before proceeding to copy... and it is even better to use time() to append to the file for avoiding any collision later on.